# 2 LinearLayouts, each half the parent size

Tags: android

I want to add two linearLayouts in my layout and I want their heights to be half the screen.

How can I Achieve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question ...... Do you want two linear layout horizontally or vertically ....

Comment: vertically and size should be same and spinner should be center of each layout

Comment: if you want the spinner in the center I dont think it cant be achieved in linear layout, try using relative layout

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you use layout_weight as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and as Virthuss mentioned, you can find more information in this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:
If you want to change the `orientation` of the parent-layout, you also have to set `width` of the relative-layouts to `0dp` and `height` to `match_parent`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```